# Autologin keeps resetting in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, login

I have autologin enabled and it works when I make changes then hit reboot yet within a day or two I have to enter the password to login. As startup programs only open when I do this I know that it has not logged in rather than logged in and logged me out.

I have a Cron job to shut down each night and the BIOS powers it on in the morning.

I have enabled the autologin option in Settings and edited `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` as suggested in https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-automatic-login-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux and other answers here but it resets within a day or two.

When editing custom.conf I have tried with and without spaces for `AutomaticLoginEnable = true` and my username.

Are there any other suggestions?

Comment: Check /var/crash for a record of gnome-shell or X-server desktop crashes.

Comment: Thank @user535733 I looked in the folder and I found gnome-terminal crash report all I could find was

' GLib.GError: g-io-error-quark: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY (0)'

It comes after messages around VNC Server (by RealVNC), I wonder if that is what is causing a problem.

Comment: My suspicion is that *something* is crashing the X stack, which loses all unsaved work and returns you to gdm (the login screen). That would require you to login despite having auto-login enabled. The report you found smells more like a symptom than a cause, since "without X11 $DISPLAY" indicates no X server running -- perhaps an attempted connection after X has already crashed.

Comment: Thanks @user535733 I think that the problem is that if the monitor is off it will not login, but if it is on then it will. Perhaps X server only starts if there's a display? I have tried looking in my xorg.conf file but it doesn't exist. I tried switching to lightdm to see if that made a difference but that didn't work, wouldn't even boot into Ubuntu.